# Vim: How do I treat wrapped lines as a separate line so that I can navigate to it with j or k?

Tags: vim

Currently if my vim tab is small enough it will wrap the text like so. When I press `j` I want it to go to the line I visually see as the next line, which doesn't have it's own line number.

[image]

However, vim just goes to the next line with a line number, so in this case it just goes to line 7 `vim.cmd ...`

Is there a way to make it treat the wrapped line as a separate line when pressing `j` or `k`?

Comment: Come on, `gj` and `gk` are mentioned right below `:help j` and `:help k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `gj`, `gk`, etc. commands, which navigate "display lines" rather than actual file lines.

I have the following in my vimrc so that the arrow keys navigate by display lines, but j and k continue to navigate file lines:

```
nnoremap <Down> gj
nnoremap <Up> gk
vnoremap <Down> gj
vnoremap <Up> gk
```

But if you want you could remap j and k instead:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
vnoremap j gj
vnoremap k gk
```